# Counting blank spaces to get word count

Tags: c++

I have a homework assignment in which I have to return the number of words in a string based on the number of blank spaces. Here is my code, I am not sure what is wrong with it but I keep getting error messages when I try to compile it.

```
string getWordCount(string sentence){
    int count = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < sentence.length(); i++){
        if (s[i]==' '){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The error messages are:

```
error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
     if (s[i]==' '){
         ^
error: could not convert ‘count’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
     return count;
            ^~~~~
```

Comment: Your `getCound()` will return 1 for empty string.

Comment: Pending the error message, it's already obvious tha the result is wrong if you have an empty string, or if the string contains only blank ;-) And what if there are two or more blanks between two words ?

Comment: In questions, post complete programs, all in one piece, not snippets. [MCVE]

Comment: C++ indexing starts at 0, not 1.  Learn range-based for loops and use them. The function is declared to return a string, but it returns an int, and `s` is not defined, so the snippet will not even compile.

Comment: I've added the gcc compiler errors trying your code. Correct if you get something different. And take the habit to be very clear on errors (see link provided by Jive) for your next question ;-)

Comment: Yes, it was just a simple mistake of needing to correct my string to an int. Thank you!! One last question, how do I make it return 0 if the sentence is just a blank space?

Comment: For starters, initialize count to zero, not 1.

Comment: I suspect that the course material has not yet introduced the C++ and standard library features necessary to do this assignment well. If so, that is a major fail, IMHO.  One cannot learn to do things well by practicing doing them badly. There follows a link to a dandy video. If my suspicions are correct, the instructor and department head would do well to view it: https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk

Answer (score 3):

To compile your code, you must ensure that return type (`count` is an `int`) is compatible with the declared return type of the function (you said it would return `string`). So instead of:

```
string getWordCount(string sentence)
```

declare your function as :

```
int  getWordCount(string sentence)
```

Note also that you use `s[i]`, but `s` is not declared. You probably mean `sentence[i]`.

Consider also solving the different algorithmic errors mentionned in the comments (i.e. wrong result for an empty string, for a string with only blank, and depending on the exercise narative, for a string where several consecutive spaces are used between two words) to finish your homework and improve your skills.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a variable named sentence but parsing on a variable named s.  Also, count is an int but your return type is string.  Try this:

```
int getWordCount (string sentence)
{
  int count = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length (); i++)
    {
      if (sentence[i] == ' ')
        count++;
    }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: She can try it. In the right surroundings it will compile, but it will not work as intended.

Comment: This does not work if there are several spaces in between two words, nor if there is a tab, nor a newline sequence.  You must count and skip whitespace.

Comment: Thank you!! This did end up working for most of the test cases. The only thing I'm still having trouble with is having the code return 0 for when the sentence only comprises of a single space.

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated plainly that this wasn't a solution to the homework assignment.  This only solves the issue around compiling.

Answer (score 0):

What they said.

Plus ...Avoid indexing with square brackets.  Use range-based for loops. Be careful about trivial input (no words, or even an empty string, in this case). Do not assume that white space is only spaces, or that it only comprises one character. Input parameters that a function does not modify can be declared const-reference, to avoid making an un-needed copy. Use `#include <algorithm>` for common tasks.

***SPOILER ALERT***. Read no more until you after you have finished the assignment.

```
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

int get_word_count(const std::string &sentence)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool scanning_a_word = false;
    for (auto ch : sentence) {
        if (!std::isspace(ch)) {
            if (!scanning_a_word) {
                count += 1;
                scanning_a_word = true;
            }
        } else {
            scanning_a_word = false;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Bonus (and better) solution.** The following does not use a state-variable (`scanning_a_word`). I call that kind of code "bread crumb programming". You leave bread crumbs along the trail to show where you've been. Sometimes birds eat the bread crumbs.  Look Ma, no crumbs!

```
#include <algorithm>
int get_word_count(const std::string &sentence)
{
    int count = 0;
    auto next = sentence.begin();
    const auto done = sentence.end();
    while(done != next) {
        next = std::find_if_not(next, done, std::isspace);
        if (done != next) {
            count += 1;
            next = std::find_if(next, done, std::isspace);
        }
    };
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally, when a variable is not declared within a scope you defined it inside something locally and it does not exist after that block of code (i.e. for loop) has finished executing. Or, you have not declared the variable at all.

```
error: ‘s’ was not declared in this scope
     if (s[i]==' '){
     ^
```

Assuming you were trying to iterate through the parameter you passed in, which is a string called sentence, I either change the variable name to s of the parameter, copy the string into another string called s, or change s to sentence in the loop. The different variations are shown below:

```
       // change parameter name to s
       string getWordCount(string s)
      {
        int count = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            if (s[i]==' ')
                count++;
        }
        return count;
      }

      // change s to sentence inside the loop
      string getWordCount(string sentence)
      {
        int count = 1;
        for(int i = 1; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            if (sentence[i]==' ')
                count++;
        }
        return count;
     }
  // create a string s, and copy sentence into string s
  string getWordCount(string sentence)
  {
    int count = 1;
    string s = strcpy(s, sentence);
    for(int i = 1; i < sentence.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s[i]==' ')
            count++;
    }
    return count;
 }
```

For your second error, generally this error occurs when there is an issue with casting a variable type to another type. In your case, the below error occurs because you are declaring a function will return a string, however, you are trying to return an int.

```
error: could not convert ‘count’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
     return count;
            ^~~~~
```

To fix this error, simply change the return type to int. However, if you really want to return the count as a string for some reason, convert the integer to a string before returning. Both variations are shown below.

```
// Change return type to int to match count's type
int getWordCount(string sentence)
{
    int count = 1;
    ...
    ...
    return count;
}

// If you really need to send count back as a string for some reason, convert the int to string
string getWordCount(string sentence)
{
    int count = 1;
    ...
    ...
    return itoa (count);
}
```

Please note: this is only describing why your compilation errors are occurring and how to fix them so that you can continue on with your homework assignment. This is not describing what is wrong, logically, with your code.

Comment: Brooke, I hate to say it, but there's a lot wrong with this answer. Even the last bits you added about adjusting count at the end and segfault are wrong. Don't take it personally.

Comment: @JiveDadson I didn't suggest adjusting count anywhere? Which piece are you talking about?

Comment: `if string length is 1 and count is 1
  return 0
else return count.`  Of course that fails on input "X";  Needing to repair a return value like that should be a BRF (big red flag).

Comment: She had asked in the comments how to return 0 if the string  is only the space. I was suggesting to check the length of the string. If the string length is of length 1 (only consists of that space)  and there has been one space found, then return 0. Otherwise, she should be returning count. I just noticed the loop starts at i = 1, which would prevent the loop from executing with a string length of one since its i < string length and will adjust accordingly. I'll look into this more and edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Take a peek at the answer(s) I posted. I have been programming in C++ since 1984, yet I still enjoy doing little puzzles like this.